# This question asking for a gender neutral alternative should be reopend

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

[Gender neutral alternative to Sir/Madam](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429000/gender-neutral-alternative-to-sir-madam)

It's odd that it was closed.

It's a very specific question, and given typical everyday context.

If you disagree - would like to clarify why it is opinion based?

Comment: Last reopen vote successful.

Comment: Why should it be reopened? Please explain how you think it meets the site standards.

Comment: @curiousdannii - from the help center: "Questions on the following topics are welcomed here: Word choice and usage"

Comment: @dwjohnston [tag:word-choice] questions are for when you want to choose between two given words/phrases. The Sir/Madam question is a single word request question and has different rules.

Comment: @curiousdannii see [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests).

Comment: Have **you** read it? Where's your sample sentence?